# Using List filter to impose a boolean condition on a list and returning a new filtered list

Tags: f#

**Given a source and target grid point, write the function: dist: p1: pos -> p2: pos -> int**

I have successfully created this function as shown below:

```
type pos = int*int

let p1 = (1, 1) // source grid point
let p2 = (3, 3) // target grid point

let dist (p1: pos) (p2: pos) : int =
 (((pown ((fst p2)-(fst p1)) 2) + (pown ((snd p2)-(snd p1)) 2)))

dist p1 p2
printfn "%A" (dist p1 p2)
```

**Given a source and a target and dist, write the function
candidates: src: pos -> tg: pos -> pos list
which returns the list of candidate next positions, which brings the robot closer to its
target. I.e., if src = (x, y), then the function must consider all the neighbouring positions,
{(x+1, y),(x−1, y),(x, y+1),(x, y−1)}, and return those whose distance is equal to or
smaller than dist(src,tg). This can be done with List.filter.**

This is what I have so far:

```
let src = p1
let tg = p2
let candidates (src: pos) (tg: pos) : pos list =
 let candi = [((fst p1)+1), (snd p1); ((fst p1)-1), (snd p1); (fst p1), ((snd p1)+1); (fst p1), ((snd p1)-1)] 
 let candilist = candi |> List.filter (fun x -> x <=dist p1 p2)
 candilist  
printfn "%A" (candidates p1 p2)
```

Since my dist function returns an int, I get an error message saying: This expression was expected to have type
'int * int'
but here has type
'int'

I hope someone can give a few tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`let candilist = candi |> List.filter (fun x -> x <=dist p1 p2)`

should probably read:

`let candilist = candi |> List.filter (fun x -> dist x p2 <= dist p1 p2)`

The filter function should return true for points which are closer to the target than the current point.  At present you are comparing the candidate point itself (of type `int * int`) with the distance (of type `int`) from the target.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. However, I only get a candidate position list consisting of [(2, 3);(3, 2)] after evaluating, despite knowing that it would take "4 steps/moves" for the robot to reach the target.
The candidate position list should ideally return:
[(1, 1) ; (1, 2) ; (1, 3) ; (2, 3) ; (3, 3)]

Comment: You're starting with the four points next to (1, 1) and then filtering out those that don't get closer to the target, which only leaves two points.

Comment: I get [(2, 1); (1, 2)], by the way.

Comment: Also - you should probably be using `src` and `tg` within the `candidates` function, rather than `p1` and `p2`, which are defined outside the function.

Comment: Excellent! I get the same as you: [(2, 1); (1, 2)] - I for some reason I switched p1 and p2 with each other.
And lastly, my apologies... I misread the assignment formulation stating:  ".... which returns the list of candidate NEXT positions...", and therefore the whole route is not asked for here :)
Cheers mate :)